# Typescript loop through object's properties and assign values

Tags: typescript

```
var roundedMachineData = new RoundedMachineData();

for (var prop in roundedMachineData) {
  roundedMachineData[prop as keyof RoundedMachineData] = 0;
}

export class RoundedMachineData {
  public constructor(init?: Partial<RoundedMachineData>) {
      Object.assign(this, init);
  }
  public running: number = NaN;
  public idle: number = NaN;
  public estop: number = NaN;
  public alarm: number = NaN;
  public operatorCall: number = NaN;
  public maintenance: number = NaN;
  public feedHold: number = NaN;
  public disconnected: number = NaN;
  public singleBlock: number = NaN;
}
```

This gives an error "Type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => number'"
RoundedMachineData is a class with just numbers as its properties

Comment: Please provide the `RoundedMachineData`

Comment: I can already tell that has a property of type `() => number`, thus, you can't assign the `number` to all of its fields. What is the expected result you trying to achieve?

Comment: RoundedMachineData is just an object of numbers. I want to be able to dynamically assign a value to each property.

Comment: Please include it, otherwise I'm not sure how I can help you

Comment: Ok I added RoundedMachineData to the code snippet

Comment: I get no error [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaDn6w)